# XeLaTex compilation error using bclogo (mps image problem)

Tags: graphics, xetex

I am trying to change from LaTeX to XeLaTeX, and I have some problems with the `.mps` images included by the `bclogo` package. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\begin{document}
  \begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!30]{Lorem Ipsum}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{bclogo}
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine with both `rubber --pdf` and `pdflatex`, but with `xelatex` I get an error:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'bc-fleur.mps'.
```

What can I do ? When trying to find a solution to my problem on the web, I found people that are using `bclogo` with `xelatex`, so it seems possible.

I am on Ubuntu, and I just installed `texlive-full`, so my `XeTeX` version is:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this line:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}
```

that teaches XeLaTeX to consider `.mps` files like EPS files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!30]{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `bclogo.sty` contains an incorrect line `\ifpdf\relax\else\DeclareGraphicsRule{mps}{eps}{*}{}\fi`.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, it should be `.mps`